# Rust Some(x) not working as I expect

Tags: rust, option-type

I'm attempting to implement a binary search in Rust (for learning purposes), and I'm using `Option<T>` to represent the return (`None` if not found, `Some(index)` if it's found).

Here's my code:

```
fn bin_search(needle: i64,
              list: &[i64],
              from: Option<usize>,
              to: Option<usize>)
              -> Option<usize> {
    let left = from.unwrap_or(0);
    let right = to.unwrap_or(list.len());

    if left >= right {
        return None;
    } else {
        let mid = (left + right / 2) as usize;
        let guess = list[mid];

        if guess == needle {
            return Option::Some(mid);
        } else if guess > needle {
            return bin_search(needle, list, from, Some(mid - 1));
        } else if guess < needle {
            return bin_search(needle, list, Some(mid + 1), to);
        }
    }
}
```

And the error message:

```
src\main.rs:22:5: 30:6 error: mismatched types:
 expected `std::option::Option<usize>`,
    found `()`
(expected enum `std::option::Option`,
    found ()) [E0308]
src\main.rs:22     if guess == needle {
src\main.rs:23       return Some(mid);
src\main.rs:24     }
src\main.rs:25     else if guess > needle {
src\main.rs:26       return bin_search(needle, list, from, Some(mid - 1));
src\main.rs:27     }
               ...
src\main.rs:22:5: 30:6 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
error: Could not compile `binsearch`.
```

I suspect the error is with `Some(mid)` but I have no idea why that's not recognized as the correct type. It is an `Option<usize>`, since `Some` is an `Option`, and `mid` is being cast to `usize`, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Your problem is not with `Option` type, but with `if` being an expression. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/37554325/5189607

Comment: @malbarbo is there a reason you don't actually vote to close the question as a duplicate?

Comment: @Shepmaster I was not sure if this was a duplicate... I think I need to read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: @malbarbo when you vote to close as a duplicate; you need 4 more people to agree with you that it is a duplicate. Unless you are a gold badge holder, in which case the duplicate automatically happens. That's why I will sometimes leave a comment instead of dupehammering — I want to poll other community members to see if they agree with my judgement. In this case, you left a comment (+1), and there were 4 upvotes (+4), then I came around. That's 6 people who thought it was a dupe ;-).

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: FWIW, my opinion is "OP should be able to take something that is ~90% of the answer and extrapolate from there or ask a new question about how to get from the end of a previous question to a desired goal", but that's not a universal belief. Feel free to pop into the [Rust SO chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust) if you wanna talk about it more ^_^

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer. I actually had no idea that if statements are expressions. My tip off should have been that the compiler error was marking the line with the `if` portion rather than the return statement.

Comment: This seems like a candidate for an improved compiler error message.